# Check-In & Checked Out files inside folder in Document library using Client Object Model

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model

I am not able checkin/checkout the files in sub folders in the document library using client object model. Below is the code I am using.

```
public void CheckOut()// CHECK OUT FUNCTION 
{
    try
    {
        string siteurl = "";
        string filePath = "";

        ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteurl);
        context.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

        Web web = context.Web;
        File file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(filePath);

        file.CheckOut();
        context.Load(web);
        context.Load(file);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        if (file.CheckOutType == CheckOutType.None)
        {
            file.CheckOut();
        }
        context.Load(file);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}


public void Checkin()// CHECK-IN FUNCTION 
{
    try
    {

        string filePath = "";
        ClientContext context = new ClientContext("");

        context.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

        Web web = context.Web;
        File file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(filePath);
        //  file.CheckIn();
        file.CheckIn(string.Empty, CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
        context.Load(file);
      context.ExecuteQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }


}
```

Comment: And what is your problem exaclty?

Comment: I am not able to checkin/checkout the files in subfolder in document library.

Comment: Whether there are any errors during execution?

Comment: No there were no any errors. The Problem is i am not able to hit on the folder(sub-folder document library)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your **Site Url** and **file path** is correct.

Example of File Path: `/sites/siteName/LibraryName/FolderName/Details.csv`